# Visual studio 2013 installation issue: not running installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm struggling on an installation problem with visual studio ultimate 2013: after the download of the web installer I tried to open it but the installer started just for a split second and than it went away, I tried with the iso, same story, tried to repair the .net framework but nothing's changed, I also made an attempt running as administrator but even that didn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really think this question is on-topic, but perhaps your downloaded file is corrupted, or maybe you need to mount/burn the ISO file instead of extracting it (I ran into a problem with this while installing VS2008 too).

Comment: I downloaded multiple times the installer, and I've already mount/burn the ISO file at list 5 times with daemon tools, thanks for the answer anyway, but how did you solve the problem with VS2008?

Comment: Tried to extract files from the ISO. Same problem like yours. Mounted it and viola, it worked. Have you checked if your system is supported by VS2013?

Comment: windows 7 sp1, I tried another time but it doesn't work, which programm did you use for mount the ISO